# SQL output to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv in this format

```
ORDER_ID    Item_DESC
 121    Beer
 121    Chips
 121    Wine
 141    Chips
 141    Wine
```

I need to push this out in this format:

```
121    Beer,Chips,Wine
141    Chips,Wine
```

Can somebody point me to the right direction, I have been breaking my head for a week now.

I tried the following:

Excel
Pandas-Pivot,stack,melt
Recursive table in SQL

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [groupby and apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   ORDER_ID Item_DESC
0       121      Beer
1       121     Chips
2       121      Wine
3       141     Chips
4       141      Wine

In [12]: df.groupby("ORDER_ID")["Item_DESC"].apply(",".join)
Out[12]:
ORDER_ID
121         Beer,Chips,Wine
141              Chips,Wine
Name: Item_DESC, dtype: object
```

Then use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) on this result.

Comment: Awesome and If i want to get only Item_DESC , then how do I change the code.

Comment: @sai Not quite sure I know what you mean. Do you mean do `list(...)`.

Comment: The output from the above code comes with the ORDER_ID and then Beer,Chips,Wine. What if I dont want the order ID and only see Beer,Chips,Wine followed by Chips,Wine in the second row.

Comment: Use `.to_csv(..., index=False)`.